# Cross Platform "Global" KeyListener in Java

Tags: java, linux, macos, cross-platform, keylistener

We're aware that Java alone cannot do a global keylistener, however, JNA can, but ONLY on Windows. We're looking for Mac/Linux versions of JNA that will allows us to do the same. We're going to implement them all, and based on which OS we have, we'll use the appropriate one.

Are there equivalents of this for Mac and other operating systems? The more OS and alternative methods, the better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[JNativeHook](https://code.google.com/p/jnativehook/) already provides this functionality.  It's a useful open source library.  As far as I'm aware, it has hooks for each operating system.  If you want to implement your own, looking at its source is a good starting point.

Comment: Thank you, we'll be looking into this!